# Вывод Output for 'Task' в VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild

Как можно изменить кодировку в output для task.json?

Сейчас при сборке выводиться следующее:
[image: Output for 'task']

Собираю стандартный vcxproj проект через MSbuild.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент VSC выдает оутпут в UTF-8. На сколько мне известно, решения этой проблемы еще нет.